# How to arithmetize labels or arrays to do calculations that are passed to a label in Swift?

Tags: arrays, swift, objective-c, xcode, uilabel

I have an app that is *almost* ready, aside from one crucial step. My old obj-C code experience hasn't helped in Swift. I either need to subtract two numbers by either referencing two UILable.text numbers (this is what I did in Obj-C) or use data from an index of two Array[atIndex]. Everything works up to this point.

```
    After some IBAction Function...

  if primeRow.count == 2 {
    let indexZero = primeRow[0]
    let indexOne = primeRow[1]
    Aa.text = "\(indexOne)" 
    Ab.text = "\(indexOne)"
    //Here I want to take the number at primeRow[1] and subtract it from the number at primeRow[0].
    //The result must be %12 to prevent a negative number.

    //My old code worked and looked like this:
    [Bc setText:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%i", (((12+Aaa)-Abb+Acc)%12)]];
```

Comment: What did your Obj-C for setting values for `Aaa`, `Abb` and `Acc` look like? Probably just one of them would give enough info.

Comment: `Bc.text = "\((indexZero - indexOne) % 12)"` seems like what you describe in the comment in your code, but that doesn't exactly square with the Objective-C that you say worked, because there you have 3 variables involved in the computation not two.

Comment: int *Aaa;   int *Abb;   int *Acc;

Comment: Chip, your code was perfect! I was so close... Thank you!

Comment: I'm glad to have helped!

Comment: BTW - I just noticed that both `Aa.text` and `Ab.text` are being set to `"\(indexOne)"` is that intentional?  Or should one of them be `"\(indexZero)"`?

Comment: The only issue is that % is not really modulo in Swift! I found a workaround since none of my numbers are that high.

Comment: What do you mean `%` is not modulo in Swift?  Can you give an example?  I have a multi-precision math library and if there's something amiss with `%` that I've missed,  I might need to revisit a few things.

Comment: You can read about it here: https://medium.com/swlh/swifts-remainder-operator-is-not-mod-a1cf17836cb7

Comment: I see what you're saying.  At first I thought that article was saying the opposite, and you're right.  Swift does produce negative remainders.  Out of curiosity I looked at this draft of the C99 standard: http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg14/www/docs/n1124.pdf to see what it had to say.  Turns out not much.  It only says that % produces the remainder, and the only guarantee it makes is that if the division is defined that (a/b)*b + a%b shall equal a.  I just tried it in C. (clang), and I get identical results as in Swift, so both are wrong.